# Trying to understand how to authenticate user/password with ucanaccess/JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am pretty new to Java and have only created some tutorial/sample console programs. I have been trying to improve my knowledge by working on a simple banking program. What I would like to do is authenticate a user using ucanaccess/JDBC. I've had success connecting to the DB and returning results from a SELECT query but now I'm trying to pass user info into the query to see if the user exists in the table.

I'm passing the variables uName and uPw from my main class from a scanner input.

The below program runs but then just terminates and I can't tell if the query executed successfully. I need some help on this part. Any help is really appreciated.

```
package exceptionsPackage;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class AccessDBConn {

    // variables
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    public AccessDBConn() {
    }

    public void connStat(String uName, String uPw) {

        try {

            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfex) {

            System.out.println("Problem in loading or " + "registering MS Access JDBC driver");
            cnfex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            String msAccDB = "Path\\bankAdmin.accdb";
            String dbURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + msAccDB;

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);

            statement = connection.createStatement();

            PreparedStatement ps = connection
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT userName, password FROM tblAuthenticate WHERE userName=? AND password=?");
            ps.setString(1, uName);
            ps.setString(2, uPw);

            resultSet = ps.executeQuery();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1) + " " + resultSet.getString(2));
            }

        } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
            sqlex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {
                if (null != connection) {

                    resultSet.close();
                    statement.close();

                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
                sqlex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "The below program runs but then just terminates " - have you tried running your code from console/cmd prompt? if you insist on using gui, you can put something like `(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))).readLine();` to the end of your software to be able to see what's happening

Comment: I am running the program in the console in Eclipse. I don't get any errors so I assume it is working correctly but what I am after is validating the select query and returning a println message like "User found" or something like that. It seems the while loop doesn't execute which is what I am having trouble understanding. I expect if the query is successful then I would see the resultSet.getString method return some values but it just stops running the program instead.